# Flutter: Best way to rebuild state when the day changes?

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management

The title says it all. I want my state to automatically rebuild when the clock changes from 23:59:59 to 12:00:00 (the next day). Are there packages that will help me do this? I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 1):

Almost any of the provider families can notify listeners on a particular condition.  Have one of those listen to a Timer.periodic(Duration(minutes: 1)) and compare old to new day.  If changed, send out a notify.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`timer_builder` package](https://pub.dev/packages/timer_builder) with an `alignment` argument. An example:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TimerBuilder.periodic(
      Duration(days: 1),            // rebuild every day
      alignment: Duration(days: 1), // rebuild on the day boundary
      builder: (context) {
        ...
      }
    );
  }
```